# MEDIAN function in Oracle SQL generates Hibernate exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have the following SQL query in a Spring Boot application. The query is within a `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation:

```
"SELECT s.libraryid, r.run_date, COUNT(*), MEDIAN(s.mean_depth) " +
          "FROM r, s " +
          "WHERE r.runid = s.runid " +
          "GROUP BY s.libraryid, r.run_date " +
          "ORDER BY r.run_date, s.libraryid"
```

The application crashes with the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 100
```

In the **application.properties** file Hibernate is configured thus:

```
# Hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

The query runs fine until I introduce the MEDIAN function. I haven't been able to find what the JDBC Type 100 is. Does anybody know?

Thanks much.

Comment: What type do you use for the `s.mean_depth` column?

Comment: @SternK : I use **float**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC type 100 is an Oracle-specific type, and it is [`BINARY_FLOAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jajdb/constant-values.html#oracle_jdbc_OracleTypes_BINARY_FLOAT).

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I solved it by writing the query using  `MEDIAN(TO_NUMBER(s.mean_depth))`. That solved the problem.